# Scripting Website Interaction With Firefox

Tags: firefox

I would like to script Firefox to do the following:

1. Open my website in multiple tabs
2. Perform some action on the loaded site (e.g. click on a button)

Preferably running some script (e.g. Python) and somehow connect to my local Firefox and send some commands over.

I know that I can do (2) on the web console with, e.g. `$x('/xpath/to/my/button')[0].click()`, so I thought of using Firefox's remote debugging mechanism, but

1. I'm not sure how to "talk" to Firefox using a script through the debugging port (i.e. what syntax)
2. Somehow I can't even get the remote debugging port to open.

I've tried the following solutions:

1. Start Firefox with `firefox --start-debugger-server 9000`
2. Enter `listen 9000` on the web console
3. Enable `Enable browser chrome and add-on debugging toolboxes` and `Enable remote debugging`
4. All of the above at the same time

But still couldn't get remote debugging to work (didn't open the expected listening port).

Any idea how I could do the above (with remote debugging or something else)?